# Structures induced from other structures

Tags: general-topology, analysis, metric-spaces, normed-spaces, inner-products

As is well known, inner products induce norms, norms induce metrics and metrics induce topologies. I was wondering, are there any other well known (or common) mathematical structures that can be added to this chain (in either side)?
$$
\text{Inner product} \longrightarrow \text{Norm} \longrightarrow \text{Metric} \longrightarrow \text{Topology}
$$

Answer (score 3):

You can insert "uniformity" between metric and topology, see [wikipedia, e.g.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_space).
If you're more functional analysis minded, insert [Fréchet spaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fr%C3%A9chet_space) between normed spaces and metric spaces. They're an important class as well. There is an even weaker class, the metrisable linear spaces, inbetween Fréchet and metric (see [topological vector spaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_vector_space)). the latter need not be complete nor locally convex, so are less useful in applications.

Also, unrelatedly to metrics or vector spaces, linear orders induce an order topology on a set.